# mailjet-apiv3-java update contact by user id

Tags: java, mailjet

While the API works using the email, updateing by userId fails with 404

```java
    @Test
    public void updateContact() throws MailjetException {
        final String randomName = generateRandomUsername();

        final int contactID = addContact(randomName, randomName + "@example.com");
        assertThat(contactID).isGreaterThan(0);

        final MailjetRequest request = new MailjetRequest(Contact.resource, contactID)
                .setBody(new HashMap<>(Map.of("Name", "Mario Rossi")));
        final MailjetResponse response = client.put(request);
        assertThat(response.getStatus()).isEqualTo(200);
    }
```

returns

```
com.mailjet.client.errors.MailjetClientRequestException: { "ErrorInfo" : "", "ErrorMessage" : "Object not found", "StatusCode" : 404 }

    at com.mailjet.client.MailjetResponseUtil.validateMailjetResponse(MailjetResponseUtil.java:37)
    at com.mailjet.client.MailjetClient.parseResponse(MailjetClient.java:297)
    at com.mailjet.client.MailjetClient.put(MailjetClient.java:192)
    at learning.MailJetApiTest.updateContactById(MailJetApiTest.java:237)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
```